# react-navigation multiple deep linking handler problem

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification

I've been developing SDK that receives push notification from FCM server. I've implemented both Android and iOS native SDKs, and I used these SDK to make React Native SDK, using platform-specific code execution. The problem I've been dealing with is handling deep links when user clicked a push notification which contains deep link for android when the app is in its foreground state. In Android SDK, when push notification is received, PendingIntent is made. Source code of destination activity is as follows.

```kotlin
class PushNotificationOpenActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        Logger.d("PushNotificationOpenActivity onCreate")
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        handleIntent(intent)
    }

    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        Logger.d("PushNotificationOpenActivity onNewIntent")
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        intent?.let { handleIntent(it) }
    }

    private fun handleIntent(intent: Intent) {
        Logger.d("PushNotificationOpenActivity handleIntent: $intent")

        try {
            // Open the URL or launch the app
            if (url != null) {
                val urlIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)).applyIntentCommons()
                startActivity(urlIntent)
            } else {
                packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)?.applyIntentCommons()?.let {
                    startActivity(it)
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Logger.w("Failed to open URL or launch app", e)
        } finally {
            finish()
        }
    }

    private fun Intent.applyIntentCommons(): Intent {
        return this.apply {
            addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE)
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        }
    }
}
```

I'm testing my React Native SDK with my own test app, which utilizes react-navigation linking handler (routing library). When user clicked push notification which contains deep link in foreground state, react-navigation raises error : **'Looks like you have configured multiple deeplink handlers'**. What I've inspected is that when app is in foreground, the  component is unmounted after new  component is mounted. The execution flow differs as follows.

1. When app is in foreground

   - component is mounted
   - react-navigation's  is mounted
   - As deeplink handler is registered in  before, it raises error.
   - Previous  component is unmounted
   - react-navigation's  is unmounted
   - Deeplink handler is removed from internal list of react-navigation
2. When app is in background

   - Previous  component is unmounted
   - Existing deeplink handler is removed from list.
   - New  component is mounted
   - react-navigation's  is mounted.
   - Since there are no existing deeplink handler in list, it doesn't raise error message.

Thus, to conclude, I want to implement a mechanism that enforces App is either reused, or unmounted before new App is mounted when application is in foreground. Please help me!

Described above ....